# ¿Cómo recibo un grupo de argumentos en la linea de comandos de python?

Tags: python, test

Por ejemplo quiero en la terminal me escriban asi los argumentos

```
$ python test.py {c,d,c} {a,c,d}
```

Es decir que un argumento sea {c,d,c} y el otro {a,c,d}, pero no logro saber cómo.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, para poder ayudarte mejor y mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta , por favor comparte el código que tienes realizado hasta el momento

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? ¿No sabés como leer los parámetros? ¿Tienes un error?

Answer (score 0):

Para recibir diccionarios desde la línea de comandos basta con hacer el siguiente proceso en tu archivo python:

```
 import json, sys
 request = json.load( sys.stdin )
```

**json** se encargará de leer los argumentos ingresados como objeto JSON y **sys** nos ayuda a obtener los parámetros (aunque no es obligatorio utilizar este último)

Ahora solo basta con ejecutar tu python y enviar los parámetros:

```
python test.py '{"llave": "valor", "llave2": "valor2"}'
```

Espero sea lo que buscabas.

Answer (score 0):

Los argumentos que reciba python serán siempre cadenas de caracteres. Es el shell quien "rompe" la línea de comandos en una secuencia de argumentos, usando el espacio como separador.

Si quieres meter espacios dentro de alguno de los argumentos (por ejemplo, entre las comas en tu ejemplo), el argumento entero debería ir entre comillas, para evitar que el shell las rompa en varios argumentos. Por ejemplo:

```
python test.py "{c, d, e}" "{a, c, d}"
```

Python recibirá en este caso tres argumentos. `sys.argv[0]` será el propio nombre del script (`test.py`), mientras que `sys.argv[1]` será la cadena `"{c, d, e}"` y `sys.argv[2]` sería la cadena `"{a, c, d}"`.

Queda a tu programa el procesar estas cadenas, si lo que necesitas es el valor de `c`, `d` y `e` por separado, por ejemplo con `str.split()`. Sin un caso de uso más claro es difícil ayudarte, pero lo siguiente puede servirte como punto de partida:

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:  # Saltarse el primero y procesar los siguientes
    print("Grupo")
    # Quitar las llaves alrededor de la secuencia de argumentos
    arg = arg[1:-1]
    # Separar por comas lo que queda
    lista = arg.split(",")
    # Procesar cada elemento según convenga, por ejemplo imprimiéndolo:
    for elemento in lista:
       print(" ", elemento.strip())  # El strip es para quitar espacios que pueda tener alrededor
```

En este caso la salida sería:

```
Grupo
  c
  d
  e
Grupo
  a
  c
  d
```